# How to prevent Excel from importing CSV values as single large numbers?

Tags: excel, matlab, csv

I'm using Matlab to output some CSV files.

`dlmwrite('filename.csv', DataX, '-append');`

which gives me pretty CSV values such as

`368,331,368,301,293,323,308
 210,766,97,105,82,90,82,97`
(rows and columns truncated, it's about 20*50)

When i import this into Excel it will read this in as

`3.68331368301293E+167
210,766,97,105,82,90,82,97`

Where it reads in the data as scientific notation, it also removes those values it deems non-significant, resulting in a few significant digits and about 150 zeroes. How can i prevent excel from randomly deciding something is or isn't scientific notation?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with the given information. How are you importing the file into excel? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are not **importing** the file but rather you are **opening** the file.  If you **import** the file the `text import wizard` will open, and you will be able to define the comma as the delimiter.

In early versions of Excel, this is a drop down next to the file open button.  In recent versions of Excel, you select the `Get External Data` tab on the `Data Ribbon`, and select the `From Text` button.

[image]